# VBA Access Need to obtain autonumber before saving new record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've got a database with a SQLServer back end which was migrated from Access and an Access front end.  After the migration one problem I keep running into is that autonumbers are not generated until after the record is saved (kind of obvious but Access didn't seem to care).  I have a form that opens to create a new record in a table, but elements of that form require the value of the autonumber (Identity) field of that new record to calculate things. I want to somehow obtain this number right as the form loads instead of having to save it and reopen it just to obtain this number. What's the best way to go about this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access databases return + generate the autonumber when the record is dirty. In the case of SQL server + Access you cannot use nor does the form display the autonumber UNTIL record save time.
The simple solution is to thus force a save in the forms data, and then any following/existing code you have will continue to work.

So your code can look like this:

```
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
  Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

The above will work as long as SOME editing has occurred. Note that if NO editing has occurred the above will NOT generate the autonumber ID (however even in non SQL server databases, when no editing has occurred then autonumber is not available anyway).

The above works for a bound form. If you have reocrdset code, then you change typial code like this:

```
Set rstRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblmain")
rstRecords.AddNew
```

In above your VBA code can/could grab autonumber. However the above code for sql sever will have to force a save.

In fact code that will work for both ACE or SQL server is thus:

will become:
    Dim rstRecords     As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngNext         As Long

```
Set rstRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblmain", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges))
rstRecords.AddNew

  ' code here does whatever
rstRecords.Update
rstRecords.Bookmark = rstRecords.LastModified
lngNext = rstRecords!ID
rstRecords.Close
```

So the simple “issue” is you need to write out the record to force SQL server to generate the auotnumber. Once you done this record save, then your forms and most VBA code should run “as is”. You do not need to "resort" to additional code such as select @@identity UNLESS you using SQL insertcommands as opposed to say above forms or recordset code.

Comment: So to clarify, your solution would be dependent on using DAO and not ADODB?

Comment: Correct. However the original post is talking about a bound form, and thus you are using DAO. However the same issue exists when using ADO against a JET/ACE database – the autonumber is available right away, and with sql server it is not. The only real difference is ADO does NOT move the reocrdset pointer after a record add like DAO does, so with ADO you can dump the requirement of the bookmark code, but the idea and concept is really the same with ADO or DAO. Since SQL server is dropping support for oleDB, then little reason exists to use ADO with Access.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped a lot, I was forgetting that Me.Dirty = False would not generate if no editing had occurred.

Comment: You can use the forms on-insert event which only fires when the user starts typing data. If they decide to close the form, then a blank record is not created. Thus one could consider to force save the current record the instant they start typing. However this potentially creates some challenges if you have required fields in the table.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the AutoNumber column in Access which is an Identity field in SQL.

The only way to accomplish this functionality in SQL is to insert the record when your form is opening and then use the @@Identity in SQL to retrieve the most recent value.

When your Access application was combined together with the database, Access was essentially doing this for you. You can check the following link for more details.

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143378-identity-sql-vs-autonumber-access

Comment: He is using a bound form and thus is NOT running ANY code to insert the record. As part of the forms record source the identity is available, but ONLY after the record is saved. So no @@identity is required, and in fact it usually not known when the form's data is going to be saved (there is no save button in Access forms).

Answer (score 0):

If its on a bound form, give a save button which will save record to database of Master table.It will have nothing except the identity field's value. Then enable or show subform which needs ID from this master table/form.

Looks @@identity code may not be possible for you since its bound form. To convince users why they need to save before adding any data to form, I name the button "show details" or "Add data to details" , this saves the record using docmd on the form, and makes visible the details section.

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

'OR a different code snippet, Just update Dirty status of form

```
If Me.Dirty = True then
   Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

'You may write code to show/visible detail section/subform